# Hibernate java ORA-02292: integrity constraint violated - child record found Course with Review

Tags: java, hibernate

When I want to delete any course with respect to its id, review related with this course can also be deleted. But there is an insue appeared on the console.

Hibernate java ORA-02292: integrity constraint violated - child record found

Course.java

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy="course")
    private Set<Review> reviews = new HashSet<Review>();
```

Review.java

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "COURSE_ID", nullable = false)
    private Course course;
```

I tried to use `orphanRemoval=true` but nothing changed.

How can I fix the issue?

Comment: Did you try adding `ON DELETE CASCADE` within the specification of the foreign key in the database itself?

Comment: @Robert Kock Thank you for your help. I assigned a action as ON DELETE CASCADE and issue can be solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the foreign key constraint in the child table as `ON DELETE CASCADE`. You'll need to invoke `EntityManager.clear()` after calling `EntityManager.remove(course)` as the persistence context needs to be refreshed - the child entities are not supposed to exist in the persistence context after they've been deleted in the database.

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "COURSE_ID", nullable = false)
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
private Course course;
```

Answer (score 0):

To assign action `ON DELETE CASCADE` in the related foreign key. In my question , I defined a foreign key to make a connection between Course and Review with a feature `ON DELETE CASCADE`. In this way, reviews related with course can be deleted when the course can be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="course", orphanRemoval=true)
```